# ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

hi good people please find the code below is running in db2 but fails in oracle.

```
select  * from
     (select distinct e.time_stamp,e.applicationid, e.processname,
     e.stage, e.initiatingsource, e.status, e.start_time, i.consultant, 
     g.cifnumber, g.applicantfirstname, g.applicantlastname, 
     case when e.branch is not null 
     then e.branch 
     else case when g.branch is not null 
          then g.branch 
          else i.branch 
          end 
     end as branch 
from (select c.time_stamp, b.applicationid, b.processname, 
        b.stage, b.branch, b.initiatingsource, 
        case when d.status is null 
        then c.status 
        else d.status 
        end as status, 
        c.time_stamp as START_TIME, 
        case when d.time_stamp is not null 
        then d.time_stamp 
        else current_timestamp 
        ens as END_TIME 
     from (select distinct f.applicationid, f.branch, f.initiatingsource, f.processname, 
             case when f.stage in ('START''END') 
             then 'APPLICATION' 
             else f.stage, f.stagecounter 
           from processmetric f) b 
          left join processmetric c on b.applicationid = c.applicationid and b.processname = c.processname and (b.stage = c.stage or (b.stage = 'APPLICATION' and c.stage = 'START')) and b.stagecounter = c.stagecounter and c.phase = 'START' 
          left join processmetric d on b.applicationid = d.applicationid and b.processname = d.processname and (b.stage = d.stage or (b.stage = 'APPLICATION' and d.stage = 'END')) and b.stagecounter = d.stagecounter and d.phase ='END')e 
left join applicationcustomerdata g on g.applicationid = e.applicationid 
   and g.time_stamp in (select max(x.time_stamp) 
                        from applicationcustomerdata x 
                        where x.applicationid = g.applicationid
                        ) 
left join applicationdata i on i.applicationid = e.applicationid 
       and i.time_stamp in (select max(z.time_stamp) 
                            from applicationdata z 
                            where z.applicationid = i.applicationid
                           )
order by e.start_time
) a 
where a.start_time is not null and a.stage not in ('APPLICATION') and a.status not in ('COMPLETE' , 'COMPLETED' , 'CANCEL', 'FRAUD' , 'DECLINE') and a.stage = 'VERIFICATION';
```

Comment: Check the syntax in `ELSE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ens AS END_TIME` it should be `ELSE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP end AS END_TIME`

Comment: [further check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571254/ora-01799-a-column-may-not-be-outer-joined-to-a-subquery)

Comment: also you have `case when f.stage in ('START''END') 
             then 'APPLICATION' 
             else f.stage` without an `end`

Comment: @vojtech The title contains the error.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle don't allow to make outer join with subquery. Following 2 joins are problematic ones:

```
left join applicationcustomerdata g on g.applicationid = e.applicationid 
   and g.time_stamp in (select max(x.time_stamp) 
                        from applicationcustomerdata x 
                        where x.applicationid = g.applicationid
                        ) 
left join applicationdata i on i.applicationid = e.applicationid 
       and i.time_stamp in (select max(z.time_stamp) 
                            from applicationdata z 
                            where z.applicationid = i.applicationid
                           )
```

You need to rewrite statement (if you need this all in one SQL) or write some PL/SQL loops through data.

Comment: No solution provided.