# Similar sql one can be executed and one get error in oracle 12

Tags: sql, oracle

This sql can run successfully in sqldeveloper

```
select *
from dual a
left outer join dual b
on a.dummy = b.dummy
and b.dummy = (select 'X' from dual)
;
```

Result:

```
DUMMY   DUMMY_1
X   X
```

This one fail and get error:

```
with b as (
    select * from dual
)
select *
from dual a
left outer join b
on a.dummy = b.dummy
and b.dummy = (select 'X' from dual)
;
```

Exception:

```
ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery
01799. 00000 -  "a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery"
*Cause:    <expression>(+) <relop> (<subquery>) is not allowed.
*Action:   Either remove the (+) or make a view out of the subquery.
           In V6 and before, the (+) was just ignored in this case.
```

So the question is the sql should be the same but why the second one got the error?

My oracle version:

```
select *
from v$version
;


Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
"CORE   12.1.0.2.0  Production"
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the issue here.

But when I used `b.dummy = (select 'X' from dual)` it gave me the same error.

But `b.dummy in (select 'X' from dual)` is working fine. Please check from your end if this helps to resolve your issue.

See the reproduced issue and resolved with `IN` code:

```
SQL> with b as (
  2      select dummy from dual
  3  )
  4  select *
  5  from dual a
  6  left outer join b
  7  on a.dummy = b.dummy
  8  and b.dummy = (select 'X' from dual);
with b as (
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery


SQL>
SQL> with b as (
  2      select dummy from dual
  3  )
  4  select *
  5  from dual a
  6  left outer join b
  7  on a.dummy = b.dummy
  8  and b.dummy in (select 'X' from dual);

D D
- -
X X

SQL>
```

You can also see this answer: [ORA-01799: a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571254/ora-01799-a-column-may-not-be-outer-joined-to-a-subquery)

Please see if this is relevant to your issue.

Comment: Thx! But I just curios why the first sql get executed but the second one not. Aren't not they are the same? Or is it a Oracle bug?

Comment: My doubt is oracle must be rewriting the query and `IN` is rewritten in different ways than `=` . my wild guess.